# Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to v0.7.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer 2.6.4 on Node 6.9.1

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var wellknown = require('nodemailer-wellknown');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "yahoo",  
    auth: {
        user: ",,,@yahoo.com",
        pass: ",,,,,,"
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({

            from        : sender_address, 
            to          : recipients,
            reply_to    : "<other_user@domain.it>", 
            subject     : "The subject",
            text        : "a text message"
       }, 
       function(error, response) {}
);
```

When running it I receive this error:

> Error: Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to v0.7.1 to use it

I want to learn to use the latest version, so what must I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is for an older version of Nodemailer, and isn't compatible with more recent versions. The given [example in the README](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#tldr-usage-example) should work without any issues for the latest version:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: '...',
        pass: '...'
    }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

var mailOptions = {
    from: '...', 
    to: '...',
    subject: '...', 
    text: '...', 
    html: '...' 
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

As you can see, the 'SMTP' string in `createTransport` is no longer required.

I've adapted the example with the [SMTP settings](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4724.html) for Yahoo. You can also use [`nodemailer-wellknown`](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer-wellknown) like you are currently doing, in which case replace `smtpConfig` with:

```
var smtpConfig = {
    service: 'yahoo',
    auth: {
        user: '...',
        pass: '...'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first variable :

> nodemailer.createTransport(<s>"SMTP",</s>{

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "yahoo",  
    auth: {
        user: ",,,@yahoo.com",
        pass: ",,,,,,"
    }
});
```

By inspecting the source code of `node-mailer` line 273

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/829ccf16eca3da686abf575eaaeea23736f85732/lib/nodemailer.js#L273

You can see the first variable cannot be a **string**

When I have an error, I searching for the error in the source code of the module, and then I can see what trigger it.

In you case, you can see that some people already reported it in the issues:

- https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/631
- https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/644